# Не работает swagger-ui на сервере, обращается по localhost вместо доменного имен

Tags: spring, nginx, сеть, dns, swagger

к сожалению, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не работает апи в свагере (swagger-ui), запросы обращаются по localhost вместо имени домена (my.domain.ru), проблема не в приложении, а в сервере, так как на другом такой же код работает. Метод свагера /v2/api-docs возвращает host: localhost , вместо host: my.domain.ru[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

думаю надо сделать как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098775/how-to-change-hostport-to-domain-in-swagger) в ответе

@Bean

```
public Docket categoryApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host("my.domain.ru") // Добываете значение сами
            .groupName("bookplatform-api")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .paths(apiPaths())
            .build()
            .directModelSubstitute(java.sql.Timestamp.class, java.sql.Date.class)
            .enableUrlTemplating(false);
}
```